# How can I rescale the r value in SphericalPlot3D for the Colorfunction?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, color

```
r[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := -1 ((Cos[\[Phi]] Sin[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Phi]] \
Sin[\[Theta]])^2 + (Sin[\[Phi]] Sin[\[Theta]] Cos[\[Theta]])^2 + \
(Cos[\[Phi]] Sin[\[Theta]] Cos[\[Theta]])^2);
{plot, points} = 
  Reap[SphericalPlot3D[
    r[\[Theta], \[Phi]], {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
    ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[#6, {0, 1}]] &), 
    AxesStyle -> Thick, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Medium], 
    ImageSize -> 400, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[r[\[Theta], \[Phi]] ]]];
Row[{plot, 
  DensityPlot[y, {x, -1, 1}, {y, Min@points, Max@points}, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> None, AspectRatio -> 15, 
   ImageSize -> {Automatic, 300}]}]
```

Why my result doesn't match my scale bar. The red part should have value -1/3 but it appears to be red.
[image]

```
r[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := -0.8 (Sin[\[Theta]]^2) + (Sin[\[Theta]]^4);
{plot, points} = 
  Reap[SphericalPlot3D[
    r[\[Theta], \[Phi]], {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
    ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[#6, {0, 1}]] &), 
    AxesStyle -> Thick, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Medium], 
    ImageSize -> 400, 
    EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[r[\[Theta], \[Phi]]]]];
Row[{plot, 
  DensityPlot[y, {x, -1, 1}, {y, Min@points, Max@points}, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> None, AspectRatio -> 15, 
   ImageSize -> {Automatic, 300}]}]
```

And for this plot, r range from {-0.15,0.15}, but it seems `SphericalPlot3D` only treat abs value of r, how can I plot with {-0.15, 0.15} falls into "rainbow" range?
[image]

```
n = 10
abc = RandomPoint[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1], n]
r[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := 
  Mean[Array[
    1 (1 - (abc[[#1, 1]] Cos[\[Phi]] Sin[\[Theta]] + 
          abc[[#1, 2]] Sin[\[Phi]] Sin[\[Theta]] + 
          abc[[#1, 3]] Cos[\[Theta]])^2) &, n]];
minr = MinValue[r[\[Theta], \[Phi]], {\[Theta], \[Phi]}];
maxr = MaxValue[r[\[Theta], \[Phi]], {\[Theta], \[Phi]}];
{plot, points} = 
  Reap[SphericalPlot3D[
    r[\[Theta], \[Phi]], {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
    ColorFunction -> (ColorData[
         "Rainbow"][(r[#4, #5] + Abs@minr)/(maxr - minr)] &), 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False, AxesStyle -> Thick, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Medium], ImageSize -> 400, 
    EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[r[\[Theta], \[Phi]] ]]];
Row[{plot, 
  DensityPlot[y, {x, -1, 1}, {y, Min@points, Max@points}, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> None, AspectRatio -> 15, 
   ImageSize -> {Automatic, 300}]}]
```

This doesn't work with @Domen 's solution, can anyone tell me why?

Comment: What if you just drop the ``Rescale`` and it will rescale automatically: ``ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][#6] &)``? To remove the negative values, just wrap your function in the absolute value: ``r[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := Abs[-0.8 (Sin[\[Theta]]^2) + (Sin[\[Theta]]^4)];``

Comment: Thx for your reply, I want to keep the negative value. Because in this case r value range from (-0.2, 0.1), I want rescale (-0.2,0.1) to (0,1) then I can clearly know the r value (Representing energy) in each (r, ⍬, phi) points.

Comment: Okay, then you can manually rescale: ``min = MinValue[r[\[Theta], 0], \[Theta]]; max = 
 MaxValue[r[\[Theta], 0], \[Theta]]; r[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := (-0.8 (Sin[\[Theta]]^2) + (Sin[\[Theta]]^4) + Abs@min)/(max - min);``

Comment: Or as @Domen said at first, `SphericalPlot` automatically rescales the range to `{0, 1}`. So `ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][#6] &)` should be what you want.  Look up `ColorFunctionScaling` in the documentation.

Comment: I try your new equation for r[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_], but the value is changed, how can I keep the value r[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := (-0.8 (Sin[\[Theta]]^2) + (Sin[\[Theta]]^4); not change

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: @Domen Hi my friend, today I tried a different function(see the question above), your solution `ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][(r[#4, #5] + Abs@minr)/(maxr - minr)] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False ` doesn't work this time, can you help me find why?

Comment: @Haodong, I have fixed my solution so that it works also for positive ``minr``. Just change ``r[#4, #5] + Abs@minr`` to ``r[#4, #5] - minr``.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem lies in how `SphericalPlot3D` treats negative values for $r$. For example:

```
SphericalPlot3D[-Abs@Cos[2 \[Theta] ], {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 
  0, \[Pi]}, ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][#6] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Even though all $r<0$, the points further away from the center are red, which means that `SphericalPlot3D` automatically makes $r$ positive when feeding it into `ColorFunction`. One solution to your problem can be to recalculate correct $r$ again in `ColorFunction` and rescale manually:

```
r[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := -((Cos[\[Phi]] Sin[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Phi]] \
Sin[\[Theta]])^2 + (Sin[\[Phi]] Sin[\[Theta]] Cos[\[Theta]])^2 + \
(Cos[\[Phi]] Sin[\[Theta]] Cos[\[Theta]])^2);
minr = MinValue[r[\[Theta], \[Phi]], {\[Theta], \[Phi]}];
maxr = MaxValue[r[\[Theta], \[Phi]], {\[Theta], \[Phi]}];
{plot, points} = 
  Reap[SphericalPlot3D[
    r[\[Theta], \[Phi]], {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
    ColorFunction -> (ColorData[
         "Rainbow"][(r[#4, #5] - minr)/(maxr - minr)] &), 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False, AxesStyle -> Thick, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Medium], ImageSize -> 400, 
    EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[r[\[Theta], \[Phi]]]]];
Row[{plot, 
  DensityPlot[y, {x, -1, 1}, {y, minr, maxr}, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> None, AspectRatio -> 15, 
   ImageSize -> {Automatic, 300}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Genius, that is exactly want I want. Thanks Domen!

Comment: @Haodong I see that you have edited the question title of this post with “(Solved)”, but you’ve not marked this as an accepted answer. Can you, please, mark this as an accepted answer? Thanks! Generally, it is much better to indicate a question has been “solved” by accepting an answer, rather than editing the question title.

Comment: @CATrevillian Sure, sorry this is my first time posting a question, how can I mark as accepted, I can't find the where to click now.

Comment: @Haodong you should find a checkmark symbol near the question’s +1 and -1 vote buttons, clicking that will turn the checkmark green and “accept” the answer.

Comment: Thx, I did that.